# What is happening when you call psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpu-usage, psutil

I want to know my cpu utilization and the command seems to be `psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)`, but why do I have to say `interval=1`? What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.cpu_percent):

> When `interval` is `> 0.0` compares system CPU times elapsed before and after the interval (blocking).
>
> When `interval` is `0.0` or `None` compares system CPU times elapsed since last call or module import, returning immediately. That means the first time this is called it will return a meaningless 0.0 value which you are supposed to ignore. In this case it is recommended for accuracy that this function be called with at least 0.1 seconds between calls.

So if you pass `interval=1`, it will measure CPU utilization over 1 second. The call will block (presumably sleep) whilebthe measurement is taken.

Comment: Ahh, thanks man! Do you know any other command to get the current cpu usage without any blocking?

Comment: Read the second half of the answer. Call it with interval 0, then call it again 1 second later.